# Sending email with using "from" header

Tags: php, email

I sent email with header "from" as: `my_friend_email@example.com` and when I received it, mail from his address was there.
Example how headers looks like:

```
$headers .= 'From: MyFriendsEmail<my_friend_email@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Questions:
Can he see I have sent email from his address?
Is it legal?

I have tried to check maybe it's sent from my **ftp** but it's not :P

Comment: Do note that the (unathorised) spoofing of e-mail addresses is not quite legal and can fall under spam regulations

Answer (score 0):

No, he can't (because it's not in his mail account), unless the receiver contacts him.

Comment: So he can't see i used his email address?

Comment: Now, how should he know? The `From` header is sent from the sender to the receiver. Unless either of them contacts him, there is no way he could know that this e-mail was sent, let alone what was in the `From` header. Just give it a try with your own email address (provided you don't use the associated mail account for sending the mail of course).